# how use laravel 7 passport with mongodb?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-passport

I installed jenssegers/laravel package to use mongodb in my Laravel project, but when I try to install passport I get this error :

> Call to a member function prepare() on null

[image: Call to a member function prepare() on null]

I tried to use [designmynight package](https://github.com/designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport), but it seems it is not compatible with jenssegers v4 that I use for Laravel 7 .

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Very Simple.Without any extra package it's possible.

Only edit AuthCode.php,PersonalAccessClient.php,Client.php and Token.php in this path:

"/vendor/laravel/passport/src/"

replace this line:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
```

by this line:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Notice:if you use multi connection specific your mongo connection in all of top Model,like this:

```
protected $connection = 'mongodb';
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to edit vendor's files

Comment: if I will update the composer that time this all changes do again? any other way to overwrite all this?

Answer (score 1):

this is worked for me

1. create passport models in Models folder Authcode,Client,PersonalAccessClient,Token
2. copy original code from /vendor/laravel/passport/src/ and paste
3. edit namespace and replace

   ```
   use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model
   ```

   Instead

   ```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   ```
4. Add the following code to boot() method in AppServiceProvider.php

```
$loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
$loader->alias(\Laravel\Passport\AuthCode::class,\App\Models\Passport\AuthCode::class);
$loader->alias(\Laravel\Passport\Client::class,\App\Models\Passport\Client::class);
$loader->alias(\Laravel\Passport\Token::class,\App\Models\Passport\Token::class);
$loader->alias(\Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessClient::class,\App\Models\Passport\PersonalAccessClient::class);
```

Comment: Great, this should be accepted answer as it is actually the correct way of doing thing without touching the vendor directly. It works for me, of course with a bit of adjustment of namespace and import statement after copy paste each of the model from vendor file

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using Laravel 8 with Jessengers V4 and I had the same issue

Inside vendor of passport just replace with:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model
```

Instead

```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Everything works properly. I recommend write a script which automatically replace, maybe using command "sed" or fork the project.

Comment: It's a bad practice to edit vendor's files

Comment: Also you can fork the package :)

Comment: im getting the same issue. any solutions without editing the vendor files?

Comment: Until you cannot get an official support from Jessengers, you can make a fork of the project and that  should be works